# R: "stack" columns on top of each other

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct, data-manipulation

Suppose I have some data like this:

```
library(dplyr)

a = data.frame( "col" = c("red", "red", "green"), "coll" = c("blue", "blue", "yellow"))
```

I am trying to take all unique values from "a" and put them into a new frame:

```
final = data.frame("col" = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")
```

I tried the following approach:

```
first_col = a %>% distinct(col)
second_col = a %>% distinct(coll)

final = cbind(first_col, second_col)
```

But this does not seem to be correct.

Could someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: rbind then distinct would do the trick

Comment: I tried "rbind" and it did not work:  final = rbind(first_col, second_col)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `unlist` the dataframe into vector and get `unique` values from it.

```
final <- data.frame(col = unique(unlist(a)))
final
#     col
#1    red
#2  green
#3   blue
#4 yellow
```

A general `tidyverse` solution would be to get data in long format and get `distinct` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  distinct(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` with `Reduce` to make it

```
> data.frame(a = Reduce(union, a))
       a
1    red
2  green
3   blue
4 yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `matrix` and then concatenate to a vector with `c`

```
data.frame(col = unique(c(as.matrix(a))))
```